# Decryption Outlook Certificate Encryption mail on Android device use Certificate

Tags: android, email, certificate, pgp

I am developing a mail client on Android, so I need decryption mail send from an Outlook client use Certificate to signature and encryption, I have import user certificate on the phone and I have read user's public key and private key. I also read the rfc-1991 about pgp, but I can not decrypt the encryption mail, so I want to know if Outlook encrypt mail flow the pgp specification. I also found that the Samsung device system mail client can decrypt Outlook encryption mail, or is there any docs about how outlook client encrypt mail?

Comment: Do you have any code to provide or something you have tried so far ?

Comment: Thank you for you to modify my grammatical errors,I use google translate help to write this,my code so far is use base64 decode the ciphertext,but after this ,I can't find text where represent the pgp random key and signature.So I can not use RSA to decrypt and get the random key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook encrypts and signs email using S/MIME, not OpenPGP (unless you use some OpenPGP/MIME plugin). X.509 certificates are not used in OpenPGP either (they are used in S/MIME).

S/MIME is defined in [RFC 5751](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5751), yet it makes little sense to re-implement it yourself. There exist various libraries to help you work with S/MIME in Java. For example, our SecureBlackbox has a variant for Android in its Java edition.

Comment: Very thanks,you give me a entry point and direction,my english is poor,when I find out it,I will tell you.

Comment: I build openssl library for android,it can sign message and decrypt mail.